# Oracle XQuery - Selecting last entry which satisfies condition

Tags: oracle, xquery

I have table named SALARIES_LOG of XMLTYPE with data like this in each row:

```
<pay_rise event_id="511"><employee_id>1</employee_id> ... </pay_rise>
<pay_rise event_id="512"><employee_id>2</employee_id> ... </pay_rise>
<pay_rise event_id="513"><employee_id>1</employee_id> ... </pay_rise>
<pay_rise event_id="514"><employee_id>3</employee_id> ... </pay_rise>
<pay_rise event_id="515"><employee_id>1</employee_id> ... </pay_rise>
<pay_rise event_id="516"><employee_id>2</employee_id> ... </pay_rise>
```

For each employee_id value, if there is more than one entry for that value, I need to get **the last one** entry. In example data it would be:

```
<pay_rise event_id="515"><employee_id>1</employee_id></pay_rise>
<pay_rise event_id="516"><employee_id>2</employee_id></pay_rise>
```

Note that I don't need the entry for employee_id = 3, because there is only one such entry.

Is it possible to get such result with XQuery usage? I'm quite close but still stuck with:

```
SELECT XMLQuery(
'for $d in ora:view("SALARIES_LOG")/pay_rise,
     $e in ora:view("SALARIES_LOG")/pay_rise

    where $d/employee_id = $e/employee_id and $d/@event_id < $e/@event_id

    return 
    <pay_rise>{$e/@event_id}
      <employee_id>{$d/employee_id/text()}</employee_id>          
    </pay_rise>' 
RETURNING CONTENT) FROM dual;
```

which gives me:

```
<pay_rise event_id="513"><employee_id>1</employee_id></pay_rise> -> unwanted entry
<pay_rise event_id="515"><employee_id>1</employee_id></pay_rise>
<pay_rise event_id="516"><employee_id>2</employee_id></pay_rise>
<pay_rise event_id="515"><employee_id>1</employee_id></pay_rise> -> unwanted & duplicated entry
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query compares each pair of `pay_rise` elements separately, which is not what you want. Try this one instead:

```
SELECT XMLQuery(
' for $id in distinct-values(ora:view("SALARIES_LOG")/pay_rise/employee_id)
  let $pay_rises := ora:view("SALARIES_LOG")/pay_rise[employee_id = $id]
  where count($pay_rises) > 1
  return $pay_rises[last()]' 
RETURNING CONTENT) FROM dual;
```